# Intertwiners and $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{F}_q)$, vector space decomposition of $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, and let $G = \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F})$. The group $G$ acts linearly on the $2$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{F}^2$ and fixes the origin $0$. Hence, $G$ acts on the set $X := \mathbb{F}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, the complement of the origin. For any group homomorphism $\chi: \mathbb{F}^\times \to S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^\times$, in $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$, we define a subspace$$\mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi := \{f \in \mathbb{C}\{X\} : f(z \cdot x) = \chi(z) \cdot f(x), \text{ for all }z \in \mathbb{F}^\times\}.$$How do I see that there is a vector space direct sum decomposition$$\mathbb{C}\{X\} = \oplus_{\chi \in \widehat{H}} \mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi,$$where we put $H := \mathbb{F}^\times$?

Comment: Notice that the group $G$ plays no role in anything you wrote.

Comment: What you have is an abelian group $H$ acting linearly on a vector space $V$, you defined for each $\chi\in\hat H$ the subspace $V_\chi=\{v\in V:h\cdot v=\chi(h)v\text{ for all $h\in H$}\}$ and are asking why $V=\bigoplus_\chi V_\chi$. (Your $V$ is the space of all fuctions $X\to\mathbb C$, your $H$ is $\mathbb F_q$ and the action of $H$ on $V$ is the usual one) When you put it this way, your question is answered immediately if you know the representation theory of finite abelian groups.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Why is it answered immediately?

Comment: Complex reps of finite groups split into direct sums of irreducible reps. Irreps of abelian groups are all characters. So your $\Bbb{C}\{X\}$ is a rep which splits as a sum of irreps. All of these must be characters, i.e. your rep is a sum of its $\chi$ isotypic components, for various $\chi$.