# $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{F}_q)$, vector space direct sum decomposition of $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$, rep. theory of finite abelian groups.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, representation-theory

This is a question asking for elaboration on the answer provided in the comments here on the question I asked earlier today [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937252/intertwiners-and-textsl2-mathbbf-q-vector-space-decomposition-of-m).

Here is the question.

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field with $q$ elements, and let $G = \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{F})$. The group $G$ acts linearly on the $2$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{F}^2$ and fixes the origin $0$. Hence, $G$ acts on the set $X := \mathbb{F}^2 \setminus \{0\}$, the complement of the origin. For any group homomorphism $\chi: \mathbb{F}^\times \to S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}^\times$, in $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$, we define a subspace$$\mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi := \{f \in \mathbb{C}\{X\} : f(z \cdot x) = \chi(z) \cdot f(x), \text{ for all }z \in \mathbb{F}^\times\}.$$How do I see that there is a vector space direct sum decomposition$$\mathbb{C}\{X\} = \oplus_{\chi \in \widehat{H}} \mathbb{C}\{X\}^\chi,$$where we put $H := \mathbb{F}^\times$?

Here is the answer in the comments.

> What you have is an abelian group $H$ acting linearly on a vector space $V$, you defined for each $\chi \in \widehat{}$ the subspace$$V_\chi = \{v \in V : h \cdot v = \chi(h)v \text{ for all }h \in H\}$$and are asking why $V = \oplus_\chi V_\chi$. (Your $V$ is the space of all functions $X \to \mathbb{C}$, your $H$ is $\mathbb{F}_q$ and the action of $H$ on $V$ is the usual one.) When you put it this way, your question is answered immediately if you know the representation theory of finite abelian groups.
>
> Complex representations of finite groups split into direct sums of irreducible representations. Irreducible representations of abelian groups are all characters. So your $\mathbb{C}\{X\}$ is a representation which splits as a sum of irreducible representations. All of these must be characters, i.e your representation is a sum of its $\chi$ isotopic components, for various $\chi$.

I could not follow this. Could anybody put a bit more detail explaining why this is true?